# R maths operation NA values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R that looks like this:
[image]

And I want to perform the following operation to each column:

((abs(a-b))+(abs(a-c))+(abs(a-d)))/200
The problem is that some rows will have NA values so when I do this:

```
data$E=(abs(data$a-data$b)+abs(data$a-data$c)+abs(data$a-data$d))/200)
```

The results in the column E will be NA for many rows. Unless they don't have any NA values (like in ID1)
Ideally I would like the numerator operation to stop when it encounters the first NA. Therefore for ID 4, let's say, it would look like this:

(abs(a-b)+(abs(a-c)))/200
Therefore omitting column d because of their NA values.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Replace `NA` by 0? But -- is the semantics of that move coherent? If a value is not available, assuming that it is 0 is as arbitrary as assuming that it is e.g. 42. What you are trying to do seems ad hoc.

Comment: I can't assume is 0 because I'm calculating variability and 0 has a real meaning. the actual data is from cells in an embryo.

Comment: I guess you are not assuming it is zero, so much as assuming that it is `a`, but you are still making assumptions on missing values.

Comment: each column represents a cell that touches another cell. Some cells are touched by many cells (up to 8) but other cells are only touched by 2 or 3 cells depending on their position on the embryo. Unfortunately they are not a perfect grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution using `rowSums()`, where the option `na.rm` should be set to `TRUE`.

You can try the code below for your objective:

```
data$j <- rowSums(abs(replicate((ncol(data)-2),df$a) - data[-(1:2)]),na.rm = T)/156
```

such that

```
> data
  ID a b c  d  e  f  g  h  i           j
1  1 0 0 0  1 NA NA NA NA NA 0.006410256
2  2 0 0 0  1  1 NA NA NA NA 0.012820513
3  3 0 0 0  0  0 NA NA NA NA 0.000000000
4  4 0 0 0  0  0  0 NA NA NA 0.000000000
5  5 0 0 0 NA NA NA NA NA NA 0.000000000
6  6 0 0 0  0  0 NA NA NA NA 0.000000000
```

**DATA**

```
data <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, a = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), b = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), c = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), d = c(1, 1, 0, 0, NA, 0
), e = c(NA, 1, 0, 0, NA, 0), f = c(NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA), g = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), h = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), i = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I manually calculated it and the result doesn't work for the data with NA. Also it didn't worked with my real dataset that is bigger than the example. Thanks though

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios why not working? do you have more columns? I am not sure you want `abs((a-b)+(a-c)+(a-d))/200` or `(abs(a-b)+abs(a-c)+abs(a-d))/200`

Comment: Yes real data has up to 8 columns(a to h), and 1982 different IDs

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios see my updated solution. One more thing, I am not sure you want `abs((a-b)+(a-c)+(a-d))/200` or `(abs(a-b)+abs(a-c)+abs(a-d))/200`, since two formulas give different results

Comment: You are right I want this: (abs(a-b)+abs(a-c)+abs(a-d))/200 I just edited the question. Thanks

Comment: @ZhiqiangWang Sorry that I pasted the wrong result here....now it is the right one , I think

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios Did you try my updated solution? I guess it should work...

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios Maybe it is better to `dput()` your data and paste it in your post...By the way, I guess you need a lot of manual work when you apply the answer you accepted when you have 8 columns, but mine does not need

Comment: dput(df)
structure(list(ID = 1:6, a = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), b = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), c = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), d = c(1, 1, 0, 0, NA, 0
), e = c(NA, 1, 0, 0, NA, 0), f = c(NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA), g = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), h = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), i = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
rowSums(abs(replicate((ncol(df)-2),df$a) - data[-(1:2)]),na.rm = T)/156
Working but error
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(left, right) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
9 times repeated

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios I used `data$j <- rowSums(abs(replicate((ncol(data)-2),df$a) - data[-(1:2)]),na.rm = T)/156`, which seems no problem.... Did you clean up your global environment before you run the code?

Comment: Yes I did, 
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, j, value = c(0.00641025641025641, 0.0128205128205128,  : 
  replacement has 6 rows, data has 5
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In FUN(left, right) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In FUN(left, right) :

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios I updated my answer with your newly data. You can try the data and code of mine to see if it runs on your machine

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for persevering, just had to adjust this: data$j <- rowSums(abs(replicate((ncol(data)-2),**data$a**) - data[-(1:2)]),na.rm = T)/156

Answer (score 1):

This is my effort of using `tidyverse`. Please let me know if I misunderstood your question:

```r
data <- data.frame(a = c(40, 20, 2, 4, 5), 
                   b = c(3, 3, 5,0, 0), 
                   c = c(0, NA, 4, 8, 0), 
                   d = c(10, NA, 10, NA, 10))

library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  mutate(
    x = (ifelse(!is.na(a-b), abs(a-b), 0) + 
      ifelse(!is.na(a-c), abs(a-c), 0) + 
      ifelse(!is.na(a-d), abs(a-d), 0))/200
    )
#>    a b  c  d     x
#> 1 40 3  0 10 0.535
#> 2 20 3 NA NA 0.085
#> 3  2 5  4 10 0.065
#> 4  4 0  8 NA 0.040
#> 5  5 0  0 10 0.075
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>